# Payment Gateway Integration asp.net c# 2.0

Tags: integration, payment-gateway

Myself mendy, i am designing web application, The business required to integrate payment gateway. I searched on site regarding the flow but i could not get much info on MSDN. I want to make payment gateway using SSL and 3rd party merchant account. How can i do it ? some info regarding payment gateway could guid me to start developing the component.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to hook up with somebody like PayPal to process your payments.  They will provide you with documentation and possibly a library to access their service.

Note that your payment processor is not necessarily the same company as your merchant account.

Comment: If you're looking for different payment gateways to choose from, I've found that the simplest solution is to do a Google search for shopping carts, and almost every commercial shopping cart has a list of gateways that they interface with.  You use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you wish to integrate with a payment gateway, not write your own?

If so, the answer is that it depends on the gateway that you intend to use.  Each has their own API.

We use Iridium Corp for our products in the UK - they provide a bunch of .net components that you can just call from your code.  Paypal will provide a well-documented API.  So will some of the other big ones.

If you want some tips, you could look at some of the open-source shopping carts, which all have code to integrate to many of the big payment gateways.

Hope that helps...

Jake.

Answer (score 0):

You should give wepay.com a try. There is now a C# SDK available with a few example here:  http://bradoyler.com/post/29357874298/wepaysdk